# Query for a set with multiple options

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a SET-field where several of the options can be selected. I want to select all rows where at least one of the options I specify is set.

The options are: A, B, C and D

Row 1: `A,B`

Row 2: `A,C`

Row 3: `C`

Row 4: `D`

I specify `A` and `C`, so the rows returned should be 1, 2 and 3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET`, you could use `LIKE`:

With `FIND_IN_SET`, you would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A', set_column_name)>0;
```

[**Read more about FIND_IN_SET here.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
[**Live DEMO with the above.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d68db/7/0)

With `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE set_column_name LIKE '%A%';
```

This will search the entire column for the specified letter.

[**Read more about LIKE here.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
[**Live DEMO with the above.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d68db/8/0)

You can also use `set_column_name = 'A'` for single exact entries